# Winforms - Controls in Panel are clipped

Tags: c#, winforms

I am dynamically adding controls to a FlowLayoutpanel control. The controls that I am adding to the flowlayoutpanel are Panels that contain two controls: a Label of varying size and a combobox with a fixed size.

The problem is that the label and combobox are displayed horizontally in their containing panel (well I think). The comboboxs are clipped and are barely visible. I have tried setting the Autosize property of each panel to true but this does not help.

Is there a way to layout the controls in the panel from top to bottom (stack them)? Could the flowlayoutpanel be the issue?

Thanks for the help!

```
     private void PopulateQuestionFlowPanel()
        {
            foreach (var question in _viewModel.Questions)
            {
                //build question label
                var questionLabel = new Label();
                questionLabel.Text = question.Text;
                questionLabel.Tag = question.Id;

                //build answer combobox
                var answerCombo = CreateQuestionComboBox(question);

                //put question and answer into panel            
                var controlPanel = new Panel();
                controlPanel.Tag = question.Id;
                controlPanel.AutoSize = true;
                controlPanel.Controls.Add(questionLabel);
                controlPanel.Controls.Add(answerCombo);

                //add panels to flowpanel
                questionPanel.Controls.Add(controlPanel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: A Panel control does not provide automatic layout.  Set the label and combo's Location and Size properties.  Or use a UserControl.  Or make this work in the designer first and look at the designer generated code to get this right.

Comment: Thanks.. I think a usercontrol is a good idea

Comment: @HansPassant The user control solution worked nicely. If you add an answer I'd select it.

Comment: @Nick: can you share codes and how did you make a usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to use a TableLayoutPanel and remove all Column's than you could do that :

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var question in _viewModel.Questions)
            {
                //build question label
                var questionLabel = new Label();
                questionLabel.Text = question.Text;
                questionLabel.Tag = question.Id;

                //build answer combobox
                var answerCombo = CreateQuestionComboBox(question);

                //put question and answer into panel            
                var controlPanel = new Panel();
                controlPanel.Tag = question.Id;
                controlPanel.AutoSize = true;
                controlPanel.Controls.Add(questionLabel);
                controlPanel.Controls.Add(answerCombo);

                //add panels to flowpanel
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(controlPanel, i);
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = i++;
            }
```